# What is the correct terminology for an "official" SSL certificate?

Tags: networking, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

What is the correct terminology or wording for an SSL certificate that you have bought from a certified provider (e.g. GoDaddy or something) and has been signed by a root certificate authority?

For example, I'm writing these statements:

> Our internal servers have self-signed certificates, but our public Web
>   server has **an official certificate that has been signed by a root
>   certificate authority**.

What is the correct term for the boldfaced words above?

Comment: There is no such thing has an official certificate, it's a certificate signed by a CA( certificate authority).

Comment: Technically every certificate is signed by a CA, even when self-signed. It's the trust that matters.

Comment: http://blog.pluralsight.com/top-reliable-ssl-certificates

Comment: https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-are-certification-authorities-trust-hierarchies/

Comment: @DanielB - If a self-signed certificate is signed by a CA then it would be trusted by browsers and operating systems.  You should clarify that a self-signed certificate the certificate authority would be "yourself" saying anything else makes it sound like it would be signed by a root CA.

Comment: Self-signed certificates can be signed by a self-signed CAs or not. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024393/difference-between-self-signed-ca-and-self-signed-certificate

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no official name for them.

They are commonly known as *Signed* or **CA-Signed certificates**. In some other places they are called *trusted certificates*, *real certificates*, *true certificates* or *non-self-signed certificates*.